# How to detect that user already login gmail in iphone's settings?

Tags: ios, gmail, google-calendar-api, autologin

I want to detect that user already login gmail in iphone's settings?  And also I want to know, whether it is possible to an event to google calendar from my App for who signed in iphone/ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Apple doesn't provide an API for that. But we can check if gmail id logged in not using

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])

```
{

}
```

/*!

```
@method     canSendMail

@abstract   Returns <tt>YES</tt> if the user has set up the device for sending email.

@discussion The client may continue to set the recipients and content if the return
```

value was YES.  If NO

```
            was the result, the client has a couple options.  It may choose to simply notify the user of the inability to

            send mail, or it may issue a "mailto" URL via <tt>-[UIApplication openURL:]
```

.

*/

If its possible just increasing my curious

Thanks !!!